# google map is not working inside app

Tags: android, google-maps

I am stuck with a strange problem
My google maps was working well on my asus device but now that I have installed it as an APK file on my tablet(I mean I have deleted the debug program and installed the version that I had produced from the manifest file) but the g.maps still not working.
Consider this that I have switched the API KEYS with the new ones.but the problem still exists.that means when I produce an APK file and install it on my tablet the google maps is not working but when I run that codes in debug mode with the new keys it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

The key is generated from your `keystore file` so if you build you app with a different `keystore file` the map will not work.

Comment: The API key that I have used was specially for this application

Comment: When you build you apk file make sure that to clean and refresh the project first after you have changed the api key

Comment: How are you using the mapFragment are you creating it in the xml or in the code??

Comment: yes,i have used that      <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_width="565dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

Comment: the file that is placed in bin directory is working fine on the device but the file that I exported from the manifest file didn't work I do this for exporting http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/06/install-android-application-on-android.html

Comment: Be sure that you don't have a layout file in the layout-large or layout-large-land with the same name!

Comment: And if you build your app like in the tutorial you dont have the keystore file before after you have exported the app so there is no way for you to to get the SHA1 fingerprint?

Comment: I have used layout-sw600dp and layout-sw720dp for changing the size
I haven’t used this documents In a separate program but my problem still exists
Sorry but I couldn’t get you

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your HA1 key that you use to create Google map v2 api key. If the Google map v2 create HA1 key is different form you create apk HA1 key then Google map v2 do not show in Android Device.

Thanks

Comment: I have checked there wass no problem there. And also the API KEY of my debug program is different with the application one.

Comment: If "API KEY of my debug program is different with the application one" then map do not show. need same api key.